# Keybindigs conflict between minor modes

Tags: key-bindings, major-mode, minor-mode

The configuration that I have for python mode implies loading both `elpy.el` and `python.el`. The things is that I found the `python.el` keybindings more natural than the `elpy.el` ones. And most of the `python.el` keybindings are shadowed by `elpy.el`.

I have tried adding a redefinition of the key map to the `.emacs` file, but it is not working.

This is my "raw" configuration for python

```
;; PYTHON CONFIGURATION
;; --------------------------------------

(elpy-enable)
(setq python-shell-interpreter "/home/anaconda3/bin/ipython"
      python-shell-interpreter-args "-i --simple-prompt")

;; use flycheck not flymake with elpy
(when (require 'flycheck nil t)
  (setq elpy-modules (delq 'elpy-module-flymake elpy-modules))
  (add-hook 'elpy-mode-hook 'flycheck-mode))

;; enable autopep8 formatting on save
(require 'py-autopep8)
(add-hook 'elpy-mode-hook 'py-autopep8-enable-on-save)


;; jedi config
;;----------------------------

(autoload 'jedi:setup "jedi" nil t)
(add-hook 'python-mode-hook 'jedi:setup)
(setq jedi:complete-on-dot t)            
(add-hook 'after-init-hook 'global-company-mode)
(ac-config-default)
```

And this is the redefinition I have added:

(I have added an "e" after every "C-c")

```
(defvar elpy-mode-map
  (let ((map (make-sparse-keymap)))
(define-key map (kbd "C-c e C-r") elpy-refactor-map)
(define-key map (kbd "C-c e C-c") 'elpy-shell-send-region-or-buffer)
(define-key map (kbd "C-c e C-p") 'elpy-flymake-previous-error)
.
.
.

    map)
  "Key map for the Emacs Lisp Python Environment.")
```

It did not work.

How can I change the definition of those bindings without actually modifying the `elpy.el` file